# How to show hidden categories on an Excel Pie chart using VBA

Tags: excel, pie-chart, vba

I've spent hours researching this question with no results and the Excel object model posted in MSDN has not been any help. I have an Excel spreadsheet with a prebuilt pie chart that is opened and manipulated via MS-Access VBA. The data to be displayed is populated and the resulting chart is used in an Access report. I did not build the original spreadsheet but I've modified it for my own use. A user pointed out that one of the categories was missing. Right-clicking on the chart and clicking on "select data" brings up the "Select Data Source" dialog box. The categories are listed on the right-hand side. Several were unchecked. I've manually selected them all and now the chart is correct.

The question is: I might want to unselect and (more importantly) re-select one of these categories using VBA code. I'm pretty sure I can unselect a category but once that happens it looks like it's impossible to reselect. Can a previously unselected category be re-selected using VBA?

Comment: Open the excel file, Record a macro of the steps you have to take to show this category/categories. End the recording and look at the Macro that was recorded, this should help you.

Comment: Actually, that's one of the first things I tried. The macro generates 3 lines of code:
'code'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("PieChart").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

I tried it with two separate categories unselected and recorded the macro to re-select it. The above same three lines are returned no matter which category was unselected. Running the macro recorder again with 3 categories unselected and selecting the one in the middle returns a single line of code:

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on the macro recorder, then manually filter out some categories and apply the filter, then manually reset the filters.

In my pie chart, I had categories "a" through "f", and I manually filtered out "b" and "d", then restored them. Here's my recorded code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(2).IsFiltered = True
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(4).IsFiltered = True
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(2).IsFiltered = False
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(4).IsFiltered = False
End Sub
```

To reset the category filters in your pie chart, run this (which I wrote based on the recorded code above):

```
Sub ResetCategoryFilters()
  Dim iPt As Long, nPts As Long
  With ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1)
    nPts = .FullCategoryCollection.Count
    For iPt = 1 To nPts
      .FullCategoryCollection(iPt).IsFiltered = False
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```